# Vectorizing scalar-array multiplication in Python (Numpy)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I've created a 2D mesh grid `w = np.meshgrid(x,y)` which I'm trying to input into the following function:

```
def f(w):
    eigs = np.linalg.eigvals(A0 + w[0]*A1 + w[1]*A2)
    return abs(eigs[0] - eigs[-1])
```

where A0,A1,A2 are square arrays.  But I'm getting an error which tells me that the operands cannot be broadcast together.  Basically what's happening is that the `w[0]*A1` is not vectorized and so `w[0]` is the entire block of x-values of the mesh instead of each individual x-value, same thing for `w[1]*A2` but with the y-values.

I've tried doing `np.vectorize(func)` but that doesn't work and I get an IndexError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `w[0]` is a `(n,m)` array, you can 'vectorize' by

```
def f(w):
    eigs = np.linalg.eigvals(A0+w[0][...,None,None]*A1 +
        w[1[...,None,None]*A2)
    return abs(eigs[...,0] - eigs[...,-1]
```

The result is the same shape as `w[0]`.

This works because the inner function is linear in `x` and `y`, and `eigvals` accepts a `(..., M, M) array_like` input.  In this case its input will be `(n,m,M,M)` shape.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but damn I would have never figured this out on my own.